# Email provider allowing IMAP copying, so I can automatically forward the mail

Tags: email, imap

I have two email providers, A & B, and I want the mail to converge at B (gmail account)

Unfortunately, provider A blocks outgoing POP and SMTP. However, I am able to access IMAP outside the organization and fetch the mail from A.

I know that using Imapsync will solve the problem, but I want to avoid having a computer running 24/7.

So are any of you aware of a email provider, I can use as a relay to copy my mail from A to B (gmail) via IMAP?

Comment: This is ① not a programming question and ② solvable only in ways you don't want. I'll vote to close, but which reason should I give?